# DataServiceOperationException in Lightswitch query

Tags: linq, visual-studio-lightswitch

Can anyone tell me what could possible be wrong with the date comparison here?

No property 'Date' exists in type 'Edm.DateTime' at position 60 "reffering to s.SwipeDateTime.Value.Date"

```
        var lastSwipe = (from s in this.DataWorkspace.ApplicationData.EmployeeSwipeLogs
                         where s.Employee.Id == emp.Id &&
                         s.SwipeIsValid == true &&
                         s.SwipeDateTime.Value.Date == DateTime.Today
                         orderby s.SwipeDateTime descending
                         select s).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, the LINQ provider you're using probably doesn't support `Convert.ToDateTime`. What's the type of `s.SwipeDateTime` anyway? If it's already `DateTime`, you shouldn't need to convert in the first place - and if it's *not* `DateTime`, it probably should be. Note that you can use `DateTime.Today` instead of `DateTime.Now.Date`, and personally I'd move that to before the query.

Comment: @cmaduro: Yes, as a local variable. Then the expression `DateTime.Today` doesn't need to be translated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Entity framework then you are right the EDM.DateTime does not have a .Date property. Check out [EDM.DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387157.aspx) for what methods you can use.

Answer (score 1):

You may also find [Entity Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions_methods) useful. These allow you to use some methods that you otherwise wouldn't be able to use.

You'll need to add:

- An assembly reference in your project to *System.Data.Entity* (in
  System.Data.Entity.dll)
- An Imports/using *System.Data.Objects* statement in the class that you're using the functions